# Internal.cleanup_server_retention_window does not function properly

Tags: sql, sql-server

SSISDB Database has become so huge in size and clean-up task is required but nothing seems to work

The size of my SSISDB log data is currently really huge (112 GB). When investigating why it reached such huge size, I realized that the SSIS maintenance job was not migrated during the server migration. I tried to clean up the log data by using the built-in stored procedure ***[internal].[cleanup_server_retention_window]*** and setting the retention_window to 7 days (The database has not been cleaned up for more than 3 months)

However, the stored procedure does not seem to decrease the size. Instead it took so long (many hours) to complete and made some table larger, e.g. ***[internal].[event_message_context]***. Does it mean that while cleaning up /deleting the log entries, the stored procedure also inserted new logs into the table?

Other options (see below) that I have found on the internet does not seem to function either. It took so long to complete and the size does not seem to decrease.

http://cryptoknight.org/index.php?/archives/1-SSIS-Maintenance-Script.html

I'm expecting to find a solution that can help me drastically reduce the size of my log data and to keep the retention only for 3 days.

P.S.:I'm allowed to disable the SQL Server Agent during the clean up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with SQL Server. For version  2017, the Microsoft has released patch via CU 17. The issue is mentioned here

[Issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4538447/fix-cleanup-server-retention-window-does-not-function-correctly-when-y)

You can download the latest CU using the following [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128).